# PHP submit to a database table only for authenticated users

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin, localhost

EDIT: The code now works. Added some code to the initial source code below.

So I have a database named payload and in it there's two tables; one named users and the other named tohere. Both of these tables just have two columns; userName and password. The tohere table is empty. The users table, however, has two populated rows. First row has admin and admin123 as the userName and password respectively. The second row has visitor and visitor123 as the userName and password respectively. There's a HTML form with two input fields where users enter a username and password. Now the idea is, if the username and password they enter in the form matches the records in the users table, I want those contents submitted to the tohere table which is currently empty. How do I accomplish that?

I have tried the following code which doesn't seem to work;

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>
        </title>
<?php
$message     = "";
$theusername = $_POST['userName'];
$thepass     = $_POST['password'];
if (count($_POST) >
    0) {
    $conn   = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "payload");
    $result = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM users WHERE     userName='" . $_POST["userName"] . "' and password = '" . $_POST["password"] . "'");
    $count  = mysqli_num_rows($result);
    if ($count == 0) {
        $message = "Invalid Username or Password!";
    } else {

        $sqltwo = "INSERT INTO tohere (userName, password) VALUES ('$theusername', '$thepass')";
//The below if statement was missing.
if(!mysqli_query($conn, $sqltwo)){
    echo "Failed!";
}
else{
    echo "Success!";
}
    }
}
?>
</head>
    <body>
        <form action="" method="post" name="frmUser">
            <div class="message">
                <?php if ($message != "") {echo $message;}?>
            </div>
            <table align="center" border="0" cellpadding="10" cellspacing="1" class="tblLogin" width="500">
                <tr class="tableheader">
                    <td align="center" colspan="2">
                        Enter Login Details
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr class="tablerow">
                    <td>
                        <input class="login-input" name="userName" placeholder="User Name" type="text"/>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr class="tablerow">
                    <td>
                        <input class="login-input" name="password" placeholder="Password" type="password"/>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr class="tableheader">
                    <td align="center" colspan="2">
                        <input class="btnSubmit" name="submit" type="submit" value="Submit"/>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

So far, this code works, but only partially. When I enter username and password not in the users table, I get the message "Invalid Username or Password!", which is fine, but when I enter records that are in the users table, the form does not get submitted to the tohere table. In fact, nothing happens. Just a blank white screen. What gives?

Comment: White screen? Check your server errors logs / turn on (or up) your error reporting and possibly display_errors too.

Comment: Make sure you have error reporting turned on `ini_set('display_errors', 1);ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);error_reporting(E_ALL);`

Comment: **Never store plain text passwords!** Please use ***PHP's [built-in functions](http://jayblanchard.net/proper_password_hashing_with_PHP.html)*** to handle password security. If you're using a PHP version less than 5.5 you can use the `password_hash()` [compatibility pack](https://github.com/ircmaxell/password_compat).  ***It is not necessary to [escape passwords](http://stackoverflow.com/q/36628418/1011527)*** or use any other cleansing mechanism on them before hashing. Doing so *changes* the password and causes unnecessary additional coding.

Comment: [Little Bobby](http://bobby-tables.com/) says ***[your script is at risk for SQL Injection Attacks.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)*** Learn about [prepared](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) statements for [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php). Even [escaping the string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5741187/sql-injection-that-gets-around-mysql-real-escape-string) is not safe!

Comment: In your else condition you never execute the insert.

Comment: you didn't write code for successful execution

Comment: @jasinthpremkumar Well noted! It now works! Thanks! Updated my question with a solution to it.